# asp.net using loginview and login status without membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

I have login control on my asp.net web site with custom Authenticate does it possible to use login status, login view without any membership provider?

All i need is remember me function and check if use is logged in and whats is username

This is my custom authenticate:

```
  string username = Login1.UserName;
        string password = Login1.Password;


        bool result = UserLogin(username, password);
        if (result)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
 private bool UserLogin(string userName, string password) 
    {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var _SelectedName = (from d in db.users where d.username == userName && d.password == d.password select d.username).SingleOrDefault();

        if (_SelectedName == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `LoginStatus` and `LoginView` controls without a membership provider. They only require that `HttpContext.User` be properly set, which the `Login` control should handle for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. To use `LoginStatus`, for example, just put `<asp:LoginStatus runat="server" ID="loginStatus" />` on the page.